# Which is a more efficient way to write this block of code

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, execution

I am writing a module that will generate a DDL based on certain input files. I am trying to figure out which way is more efficient.

This:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Common.testFields.size(); i++) {
    line = "";
    line += "  " + Common.testFields.get(i).toString() + "  ";
    line += Common.dataTypes.get(i).toString(); 
    if (i != Common.testFields.size() - 1) 
        line += ",";
    ddl += line;
    if (i != Common.testFields.size() - 1) 
        ddl += "\n";
}
```

or this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Common.testFields.size(); i++) {
    line = "";
    line += "  " + Common.testFields.get(i).toString() + "  ";
    if (i == Common.testFields.size() - 1) {
        line += Common.dataTypes.get(i).toString(); 
        ddl += line;
    }
    else {
        line += Common.dataTypes.get(i).toString() + ",";
        ddl += line + "\n";
    }
}
```

I timed the execution for both `for` loops using `System.currentTimeMillis()`, but when I print out the elapsed time, it prints out 1 millisecond for both. `Common.testFields.size()` is currently 165. Considering the fact that both of these have the same complexity of `O(n)`, If `Common.testFields.size()` were considerably larger, say 1000 or even 10000 times larger than it is currently, which one of these,if any, would be faster?

Comment: If you are really concerned about performance here, use a StringBuffer

Comment: Additionally, I wouldn't be surprised if the Java compiler just optimizes both of your snippets to (roughly) the same Java byte code

Comment: and you can avoid the last entry check inside the loop by moving the code executed for the last entry outside the loop and decreasing the number of loop iterations by 1

Comment: Stop wasting your time with these kind of optimizations! Grab a profiler and **measure where the bottleneck of your application actually is** and try to optimize that!

Comment: @DavidtenHove You meant StringBuilder?

Comment: Why does it matter? Write it to be as readable as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am actually writing this to be added to an existing application, which is why I am outputting a `String` instead of a `StringBuilder`. I didn't think this would make a whole lot of difference. I was just curious to see if the 2 `if` statements would logically take longer than the `if-else`.

Comment: Strings are immutable which means that when you willy nilly create new strings all over the place, you create extra work for the garbage collector thus consuming more CPU time to clean up your mess, and you can still return a String if you construct your return value with a StringBuilder.

Comment: `StringBuffer` is the thread-safe version of `StringBuilder`. Either of which are what you should be using.

Comment: Doesn't Java do the same thing as C# when it comes to strings like this? Isn't it compiled so that a StringBuilder is used even if you didn't specify it?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn yes it is, though I don't know the specifics (like if the construction of the stringbuilder can be pulled out of a loop body etc...)

Comment: This sounds like the perfect case where you write your code and let the compiler do it's thing. It's already been identified that they're both O(n) and already running at ~1ms times. Unless this is a real time system plotting missile paths, either one is fine.

Comment: Thank you all for the help. My suspicions were confirmed. I did however convert to `StringBuilder`s instead of `Strings` just in case.

Comment: I need the loop to complete. If i only increment the counter to size() - 1, I will lose a line of data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My favorite "join" pattern is this:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String separator = "";

for (int i = 0; i < Common.testFields.size(); i++) {
    builder.append(separator)
           .append("  ")
           .append(Common.testFields.get(i))
           .append("  ")
           .append(Common.dataTypes.get(i));

    separator = ",\n";
}

String ddl = builder.append("\n").toString();
```

No special case "if last" or "if first" necessary.

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

```
//assuming
String ddl = new String("")

for (int i = 0; i < Common.testFields.size(); i++){
    ddl += "  "
         + Common.testFields.get(i).toString()
         + "  "
         + Common.dataTypes.get(i).toString()
         + ",\n";
}

ddl = ddl.substring(0, ddl.length()-3);
ddl += "/n";
```

Comment: clean and readable. there are two bugs in here: `ddl.substring(0, ddl.length()-3);` should be `ddl.substring(0, Math.max(0, ddl.length()-2));`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure, you'll have to measure.

```
// the JIT might be able to do this optimisation, but lets be sure
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

// resolve this just once (assuming it stays the same during your loop), you never know how the VM is going to do this lookup
// also change type of list to the type of Common.testFields
ArrayList<? extends Object> fields = Common.testFields;
ArrayList<? extends Object> data = Common.dataTypes;
for (int i = 0, size = fields.size(); i < size; i++) {
    builder.append("  ").append(fields.get(i)).append("  ").append(data.get(i));
    if (i != size - 1)
        builder.append(",\n");
}
ddl = builder.toString(); // or += or whatever the previous state of ddl is...
```